# Backbone error line 219 is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, console.log

Hy! I'm trying to use backbone, but no matter what i try, this message appears on my console:

```
TypeError: _ is undefined                                      backbone.js (line 219)
_.each(listenMethods, function(implementation, method) {
```

my code looks like this

```
<body>

<script src="js/external/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/external/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/external/underscore.js"></script>

<script>
// some text
</script>

</body>
```

I'm sure that this is the correct path to the files, because I used Dreamweaver's browse

Comment: Backbone depends on Underscore. Load Underscore first.

Answer (score 3):

switch the order of your libraries, have underscore before backbone